# Veracrypt somehow really messed up the bootloader on my PC

Tags: windows, encryption, data-recovery, bootloader, veracrypt

So basically I wanted to install windows on a secondary physical drive in my PC so I could have a second bare metal OS for testing stuff. I have 1 M.2 SSD that has my main windows installation encrypted with bitlocker(with preboot pin) and 2 SATA HDD’s. One of these HDD’s is for extra storage on my main OS and is also encrypted with bitlocker and the other is empty and that is the one I used to install a second windows OS on.

I formatted it into one NTFS partition and installed windows on it then booted to my new OS to install veracrypt. The options I selected were: “encrypt the system drive”, “encrypt whole drive” (Originally I was just going to encrypt the windows partition but it said some shit about it being only 1 partition and that I should encrypt the whole drive so I did), and “encrypt host protected area”. After this I set my password and did the encryption pre-test.

This is where things went wrong, my password didn’t work no matter how many times I tried it, a little annoyed but whatever, I shut off my PC and figured I'd just restart the whole install and be more careful setting my password, I loaded into the BIOS so I could boot back into my main OS on the M.2 drive, but no matter what I boot to I always get that Veracrypt password prompt, which never works, I even physically disconnected all other drives except the M.2 and I STILL keep getting prompted for a password that doesn’t work. Somehow veracrypt screwed with my main OS and wrote something to my main drive.

I have no idea how this even happened and have no clue in the slightest how to fix it. Any help in undoing whatever Veracrypt did would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a lot of text, I just want to give every detail possible in case it helps in any way.

Comment: You have to modify your UEFI boot.  You should never create partitions on a disk that you intend to boot Windows from.  WinPE will create all required partitions.  By installing it the way you did, you modified the EFI partition on the primary drive, and by default your new installation is the default selection.  You will need to change that in order to boot to your original configuration.  Your difficulty is also one of the reasons, you shouldn't attempt to encrypt the entire the disk one storage device with BitLocker and the other with VeraCrypt.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be restore from the drive images you must have made before those drive changes.

Comment: So you're saying I need to modify the EFI partition on my primary drive(the M.2) and remove the Veracrypt bootloader from it? If so how do I do this?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I didn't make any drive images because I never expected Veracrypt to touch my main drive, I though it would only touch that secondary drive on which I installed windows. I do however have the bitlocker recovery keys for both my M.2 and the HDD storage drive backed up on a USB so worst case I can use those to recover my data.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who might have a similar problem, you can bypass the Veracrypt password screen by pressing escape, which they annoyingly don't tell you on the screen itself.

I did this and booted back into the second OS, and Veracrypt said the pre-encryption test failed and gave me the option to remove its pre-boot configurations (or some similar message). After this I'm able to boot into my main and secondary OS without a problem.